# Python dependency issue

Tags: python, dpkg, dependencies

After trying to install python2.7.13 I have lost the ability to use my Ubuntu.

I have tried `sudo apt-cache policy python2.7 python2.7-dev` which gave me:

```
python2.7:
  Installed: 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3
  Candidate: 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3 0
        500 http: // ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http: // security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.6-8 0
        500 http: // ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
python2.7-dev:
  Installed: 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3
  Candidate: 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3 0
        500 http: // ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http: // security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.6-8 0
        500 http: // ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

and `sudo apt-cache policy python`:

```
python:
  Installed: 2.7.13-1
  Candidate: 2.7.13-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.13-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.5-5ubuntu3 0
        500 http: // ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

which are different versions... I tried `apt-get -f install` which gave me:

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

and `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` gave me:

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

I have no idea what to do...

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update`.

Please let me know if this does not solve the problem for you.